# Trying to fetch image from database in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I was uploaded Image in database Successfully. But not succeed to fetch image from database.
i want to fetch the image from database.

here is my code,
controller -> login.php

```
public function user_update(){


            $this->load->model('login_model');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('cnumber', 'Contact Number','required|min_length[10]|max_length[10]|numeric');

                $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'doc|docx|pdf|gif|jpg|png|xlsx';
                $config['max_size']             = 10000;
                $config['max_width']            = 1024;
                $config['max_height']           = 768;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                if (( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image')) && ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE ))
                {


                        $this->load->view('student/home');
                }
                else
                {
                      $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                    $image_name=($data['upload_data']['file_name']);
                        $resume=base_url().$image_name;

                    $udata = array(
                        'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
                        'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
                        'mname' => $this->input->post('mname'),
                        'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
                        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                        'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
                        'cnumber' => $this->input->post('cnumber'),
                        'image'=> $resume
                );
                $this->login_model->Updateuser($udata);
                }
}
```

model file:- login_model.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class login_model extends CI_Model
{
function Updateuser($param) {

        $id = $param['id'];

        $usar1 = array(
            'Student_Name' => $param['fname'],
            'm_name' => $param['mname'],
            'l_name' => $param['lname'],
            'Student_Email' => $param['email'],
            'contact_no' => $param['cnumber'],
            'Address' => $param['address'],
            'image' => $param['image']

            );
        $this->db->where('Student_id', $id);
        $this->db->update('students', $usar1);
        //echo ($this->db->last_query());
        //exit();
        $sturesult = $this->login_model->get_student_list();
        $data['Stulist'] = $sturesult;
        $this->load->view('student/default_list',$data);

     }
}
```

view file:- edit_info.php

```
<div class="container" id='main-layout' style="border-top: 1px solid #D14B54; background: #f5f5f5f5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8">
            <div class="ajaxResponse"><input type="hidden" name="ajaxResponse"></div>
            <div class="row" style="padding: 10px 5px;">
                <?php $id = $this->uri->segment(3); if(!empty($id)): ?>
                <div class="">
                <?php echo validation_errors(); 
                echo $lname;
                ?>

                    <div class="thumbnail  familycol" style="padding:16px">
                          <?php echo form_open_multipart('login/user_update'); ?>
                          <legend>Personal Information</legend>
                            <div class="row">

                                <?php //echo form_label('Id :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('id'); ?>
                                 <input type="hidden" name="id"  value="<?php echo $row->Student_id; ?>" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="id"/>
                                   <!-- <label class="required">First name</label>-->



                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                                <label for="First Name">First Name:</label>
                                    <input type="input" name="fname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row->Student_Name;?>"/><font color="red"><?php echo form_error('fname'); ?></font>


                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">

                                    <!--<label class="required">Middle name</label>-->
                                    <label for="Last Name">Middle Name:</label>
                                    <input type="input" name="mname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row->m_name?>"/><font color="red"><?php echo form_error('mname'); ?></font>

                                </div>
                               </div>
                               <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                                    <!--<label class="required">Last name</label>-->
                                    <label for="Last Name">Last Name:</label>
                                    <input type="input" name="lname" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row->l_name ;?>"/><font color="red"><?php echo form_error('lname'); ?></font>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                                <?php echo form_label('Email :'); ?> <?php echo form_error('email'); ?>
                                    <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $row->Student_Email; ?>" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Email"  />
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <!--<label>Address</label>-->
                                    <label for="text">Address</label>
                                    <textarea name="address" class="form-control"><?php echo $row->Address ;?></textarea><font color="red"><?php echo form_error('address'); ?></font>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6">
                                    <label for="text">Contact Number</label>

                                    <textarea name="cnumber" class="form-control"><?php echo $row->contact_no ;?></textarea><font color="red"><?php echo form_error('cnumber'); ?></font>
                                </div>

                                <br/>
                            </div>
                            <br/>
                                <label for='uploaded_file'>Select A File To Upload:</label>
                                <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" value="upload">

                            <br/>
                            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block signup-btn" type="submit" style="margin-top: 5px;">
                                Update my Profile</button>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php endif;?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Lets Put Code in your View file:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/').$Stulist[$i]->image; ?>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have updated the wrong image directory of uploaded images in database.

Simply update the following lines of code

```
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
$image_name=($data['upload_data']['file_name']);
$resume=base_url().$image_name;
```

to

```
$data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
$image_name=($data['upload_data']['file_name']);
$resume=base_url('uploads').$image_name;
```

here the base_url points to the uploads directory where you have uploaded  your images.